# Solving an equation in the complex field - radius of circle

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a problem which is really easy but for some reason I don't understand what's going on here.

The assignment says: Solve the following equation in the field of complex numbers: $$z^4 -16=0$$ and present the solutions in the complex plane.

Now obviously I did this: $$z = \sqrt[4]{16}$$ which can be solved with
$$\sqrt[n]{w} = r\large {e}^{i\frac{\LARGE{\phi + 2k\pi}}{\LARGE{n}}}, k=0,1,2...n-1$$

So as my complex number is $16$, the magnitude or $r$ of this complex number is also 16, right? Which would mean that the radius of my circle in the complex plane is also 16, but in the solutions it is $2$. I get the angles right and I generally know how to operate with complex numbers but I can't figure out where I am wrong here.

Comment: $r$ is the *fourth root* of 16, per the formulas you wrote down.

Comment: If you don't use any complex analysis, $z^4 - 16 = 0 \implies (z^2-4)(z^2 + 4) = 0 \implies z = \pm 2, \pm2i$

Answer (score 1):

It should be $$\sqrt[n]{w} = \sqrt[n]r\large {e}^{i\frac{\LARGE{\phi + 2k\pi}}{\LARGE{n}}}, k=0,1,2...n-1.$$
Another way:
$$z^4-16=(z^2-4)(z^2+4)=(z-2)(z+2)(z-2i)(z+2i)$$ and we obtain all roots.

Answer (score 0):

$16$ is the magnitude or $z^4$, so the magnitude of $z$ is $2$. We have in polar coordinates $$z^4=16=2^4=2^4e^{2ik\pi}, \space\space k\in\mathbb Z$$

so $$z=2e^{i\frac{k\pi}{2}}, k\in\mathbb Z$$

which has only $4$ different values for $k\in\mathbb Z$, that is for $k=0,1,2$ and $3$.